Recovered Files from Deleted Partition Are Empty, How Can I Fix This?
I accidentally deleted a partition on my hard drive and used a file recovery tool to restore the files. The recovery process seemed successful as the files were restored with the correct extensions and sizes. However, none of the files open correctly. When I open them in a text editor (Notepad), they appear empty with no binary content.
What steps can I take to resolve this issue and properly recover my files?
Thanks in advance

did you recover the contents to other media, or did you try to restore them in place? if you were smart and haven't written to the disk the partition was on since the incident, then I'd try again, using TestDisk to recover the whole partition to another disk.

The tools used to restore the partition and to recover the files likely reduced any chance of recovering them. The best thing to do would be to stop using the drive and to make a verbatim, forensic image of the whole drive. Then you or a commercial recovery service could work on the image. Of course, if the data were important enough to pay for commercial data recovery, you would have periodically made drive images to restore.
